# Installing TestFlight on iOS 7

Tags: testflight, ios7

After upgrading my iPhone 5 to iOS 7 beta, it seems I have to re-connect it to Testflight.
Unfortunately, I can't install the provisioning profile:

After selecting 'Reconnect Device', 'Install Profile', 'Install Now', the alert is 'Profile Installation Failed. You iPhone is not activated'

I tried to remove the previous profiles, clear Safari cache and reboot, but no success...

Comment: You shouldn't install iOS 7 beta on your carry device, or, main iPhone ! Anyway, you should probably just go to the [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com) for help on this.

Comment: Probably.... but once of the iOS 7 features has a big impact on your application!

Comment: I had the same issue after restoring my backup to iOS 7. After restoring it again, I removed all profiles, removed the TestFlight icon, cleared the Safari cache, and removed the device from my devices list on TestFlight (not sure if all of this is necessary). Then I visited http://testflightapp.com/m/login, logged in, and could connect my device. It did not install the profile (or the TestFlight icon on the homescreen) though. But I can install beta apps from the TestFlight mobile application in Mobile Safari.

Comment: @LysannSchlegel I opened up a chat room to discuss it. Its coding related because without this we can keep coding :)  I removed all profiles from my device and logged in thru the mobile site like you said but I get a message saying my phone is not activated :(

Comment: I'm not sure why this topic was marked closed as off topic.

Comment: For those having the issue still: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1184610-beta-ios-releases-and-testflight

Comment: @Daniel regardless of whether or not someone is using their main device, it is still beneficial to use TestFlight for distributing beta builds to your iOS 7 devices when developing for iOS 7.

Comment: @ChrisWagner agreed. You misunderstood what I said.

Comment: I think all these answers and comments are confusing. Did anyone get testflightapp to work on an iOS7 beta device? How? There seems to be no way of adding an iOS7 way to a testflight account.

Comment: @Jakob Robinson: Settings>General>Reset>Reset all Settings recommended by TestFlight did not work for me (iPhone 5, iOS 7 beta 5)

Comment: @Jonny I was able to get our app installed through TestFlight by doing what Lysann did -- use Mobile Safari to load up testflightapp.com, log in, and then install the app from there. I was never able to get it to install using the webclip but was able to from Mobile Safari (this was on beta 6, FWIW)

Comment: I am having this problem even with iOS 7 GM. I get the failure to install the profile error saying my iPhone is not activated. Yet everything else works. I've tried Reset All Settings, but that didn't help. Is there a way to re-activate an iPhone?

Comment: Same here - still have the problem on iOS 7.0.2.

Comment: Check this video : https://itunesconnect.apple.com/downloads/Documentation/TestFlight-v09-iTC-Export-sw.mov

Answer (score 8):

Short answer - Go to TestFlight directly on Mobile Safari and use the TestFlight CocoaPod.

We got TestFlight working on the latest iOS 7 build.  The TestFlight "app" that installs doesn't work, but manually visiting the TestFlight site in Mobile Safari allows you to install the profile and load the app. Nothing special needed. It sometimes takes a few tries loading the profile to get it to actually load.

Also, loading our apps into TestFlight wasn't working, so we started using the TestFlight CocoaPod and it works great.

Comment: Nope it does not allow you to install the profile. Not even on the public iOS 7 release.

Comment: Give more detail openfrog. I literally just picked up my device, went to Testflightapp.com and installed an app. iPhone 5, GM iOS 7.

Answer (score 6):

I got it working on an iPad mini running iOS 7 beta 5, that was previously used with testflight while running iOS 6. It seems that it will work under some circumstances. What I did:

- Unregistered the device from its connected testflight user account (actually this step might be irrelevant)
- Launched testflightapp.com from Safari, not from any icon placed on home screen. It has to be from Safari where the url bar is shown. From here I could install betas. However the device itself is not listed under any user and it is not activated. While trying to activate it, testflight app says the registering works OK, however it really fails.

So, it MIGHT work but it's clear that the people at testflight has some work to do.

More: I am unable to get it working with an iPhone 4 iOS 7 beta 5 at all. The iPhone has not previously been used with testflight and seems to require an activation through that profile (at testflight or Apple, not sure) but the activation fails and there's no app list coming up in Safari, just the activation sequence. The key here might be that the device must have been used with testflight before, while on iOS previous to 7.

<s>It seems that using testflight with iOS 7 beta does not work and/or is not supported at the moment.</s>

Not sure what happened here but I was using testflight with an iPad mini that had iOS6. When I just upgraded it to iOS 7, the testflight site loads on the device, however installs never process.

Comment: I can confirm that TestFlight doesn't seem to be working on the iPod Touch running iOS 7 beta 6. Works fine on my iPad mini, though.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer of Lysann Schlegel most useful. After some experimenting, I found out that simply **opening TestFlight from Safari works fine**. Don't use TestFlight app icon.

Comment: Please stop adding comments to the answer section. Use comments written below the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case after i connect my iphone with the xcode/ organizer beta it let me install again the apps.

Check in Settings if you have the Developer options.

Comment: It let you install apps or let you install Testflight Profiles?

Comment: Yes. I had updated to 7.0b4 and before connect to organizer b4 it did't let me install apps, after connect it's working fine.

Comment: Yes to which question? You can use TestFlight now, or you can install apps period?

Comment: It let me install apps from test flight.
It is having problems with a new app and i hadn't time to check it, maybe on the weekend. It is making the reconnect device fine, but it's saying beta2 when is beta4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that this is currently untested and is a only workaround, but try downloading the ipa file from the TestFlightApp "Share this build" link and use xcode to install it.

This link is normally provided to allow pre iOS4 users to install using testflightapp.com

Even if this works this workaround is probably unacceptable for a vast majority of beta testers.

I'd say also use the "iphone configuration utility" but I suspect that the current release does not support the iOS beta.

If this does fix the issue for people then it's some confirmation that it's mainly the OTA profile that's at issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did a fresh install of iOS 7 beta 6 (it did not have any provisioning profiles before) and was able to load an app from TestFlight.  Installing the provisioning profile failed from the web, but I was able to get the correct one onto the device through XCode's Organizer.  Then I downloaded the app from TestFlight in Safari (not the little portal TestFlight app).  It loaded up just fine.